# Re-firing parallax.js when using Ajax Load More

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, resize, parallax.js

I am trying to incorporate Parallax.js (jQuery) and Ajax Load More (WordPress plugin) to the same page. When Load More changes the length of the page, the parallax images should re-position themselves with everythig else, but they don't, so I am left with empty spaces where the images should be.

The problem can be seen [here](https://vhe.matmartin.co.uk/) – scroll down to 'Past Events'.

I realise that Parallax needs to be re-triggered when the page is re-sized (as per [this thread](https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js/issues/268)) but I have not managed so far to write the code that will make this happen. Part of the issue may be that I'm using the [Ajax Load More WordPress plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/) and so don't have the same kind of access to the code as for the Parallax effect (I don't want to edit the plugin files themselves).

I am loading the scripts in the theme files as follows:

`<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.parallax.min.js"></script>`

and calling the images as follows:

`<div class="parallax-img" data-parallax="scroll" data-src="<?php the_field('page_break_1'); ?>" data-bleed="50" data-midnight="mh-clear"></div>`

The repeater for the Load More function is simple php which I can share if it is helpful but which seems irrelevant to this function – I'm not sure what the plugin is doing code-wise beyond that.

I am hoping for the absolute positioned elements (parallax scrolling images) to have their positions re-plotted when the page is made longer. How can I write the function that will make this happen please?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Load More has [callbacks functions](https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/docs/callback-functions/) that are dispatched after certain events that you can use for this purpose.

For this case, check out the almComplete callback.
https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/docs/callback-functions/almcomplete/

Comment: Thanks @Darren. It's not clear to me how to implement this though – I've tried adding `window.almComplete = function(alm){ $(window).trigger('resize').trigger('scroll'); };` and  `window.almComplete = function(alm){ jQuery(window).trigger('resize').trigger('scroll'); };` but i'm not seeing any change. How should I be implementing this?

Comment: You would implement inside a custom JS file or on the page itself. I suggest testing the function is being hit with a console.log

Comment: in the page itself (footer) is where i've done this. the console.log is appearing as expected but still not seeing that picture move? here's what i'm running – maybe you can see where i'm going wrong?: 
`<script>
window.almComplete = function(alm){
jQuery(window).trigger('resize').trigger('scroll');
console.log('#almComplete should have fired');
}; 
</script>`